# How do i get my output to not come out as (1, '.txt')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create copies of a txt document a couple of times to automate some of my tasks. So I created a loop that adds 1 to a variable every time it runs. When I added this to **my main code it came back with the weird output of (1, '.txt'). Is there a way that I can just get it to say 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, ect.** I thought it was an issue with the number not being a string but I don't think that is the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
num = 1
while num < 10:
    #print(num)
    num += 1
    numtxt = num
    txttxt = ".txt"
    maintxt = numtxt, txttxt
    #maintxtsrt = str(maintxt)
    print(maintxt)
    #print(maintxtsrt)
```

Comment: `maintxt = numtxt, txttxt` is creating a _tuple_.

Comment: Use `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: why `while` loop when `for` loop would do and the code will be simpler? otherwise, use f-string. at the moment you create tuple with this line `maintxt = numtxt, txttxt`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
maintext = str(numtxt)+txttxt
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line:

```
maintxt = numtxt, txttxt
```

you create a tuple.
The whole code can be just:

```
for num in range(1, 10):
    print(f'{num}.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you made a tuple by `maintxt = numtxt, txttxt`.

Instead, I changed a type of numtxt to `str` and concat with txttxt to make correct filename.

```py
num = 1
while num < 10:
    #print(num)
    num += 1
    numtxt = num
    txttxt = ".txt"
    maintxt = str(numtxt) + txttxt # fixed
    print(maintxt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `maintxt` is already an `(int, str)` tuple, you could convert it into a single joined string with `join` and `map`:

```
    numtxt = num
    txttxt = ".txt"
    maintxt = numtxt, txttxt
    print(''.join(map(str, maintxt)))
```

But it's simpler to just create `maintxt` as a string:

```
    maintxt = f"{num}.txt"  # creates a single string like "1.txt"
```

You can also simplify your `num` loop by using `for` and `range` instead of a `while` and a manually incrementing variable:

```
# prints "1.txt", "2.txt", ..., "9.txt"
for num in range(1, 10):
    print(f"{num}.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions:

1. it is better if you start your num with zero, so when you increment inside your while it will start from 1
2. str(num) will change integer to string
3. you get tuple because of this line `maintxt = numtxt, txttxt`

this code will give you the result that you want
num = 0

while num < 10:

```
num += 1

numtxt = str(num)
txttxt = ".txt"
maintxt = numtxt + txttxt
```

> ```
> print(maintxt)`
> ```